# sonarqube maven (error connecting to maven server)

Tags: sonarqube

I have installed sonarqube 5.6.6 on a linux centOS7 server.
The installation seems to be ok, given that I can access the web-interface at 95.xx.xx.xx:9000

However, whenever I try to run maven from my laptop 
"mvn -X -Dmaven.test.skip=true clean verify sonar:sonar"
I get this error:
Fail to get bootstrap index from server: Failed to connect to /95.xx.xx.xx:9000: Connection refused: connect

Why is not able to connect and retrieve the index ?
When I try from my browser to go to http://95.xx.xx.xx:9000/batch/index
it returns this line:
 sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.6.jar|d8869f7e1501c7163b7cfbec9ed6ff1d

Hence I don't understand why Maven can't access that url.

Thx a lot,
Best Regards

--------- I paste my pom.xml here below: ---------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <artifactId>reply-webseed-angular2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
         <!--    <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>  
        </exclusions> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JWT -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
            <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.github.cage</groupId>
          <artifactId>cage</artifactId>
          <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.1212.jre7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>exec-npm-install</id>
                                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                    <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp</workingDirectory>
                                    <executable>npm</executable>
                                    <arguments>
                                        <argument>install</argument>
                                    </arguments>
                                </configuration>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>exec</goal>
                                </goals>

                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>exec-npm-run-tsc</id>
                                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                    <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp</workingDirectory>
                                    <executable>npm</executable>
                                    <arguments>
                                        <argument>run</argument>
                                        <argument>build</argument>
                                    </arguments>
                                </configuration>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>exec</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                       <!--  <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                        <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>-->
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                   </plugin>

                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>travis</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
         <profile>
            <id>sonar</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <sonar.host.url>http://95.xx.xx.xx:9000/</sonar.host.url>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        <!--    <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>

          </plugin>-->
        </plugins>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            org.codehaus.mojo
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            exec-maven-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [1.3.2,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>exec</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <execute/>
                                        <!-- <ignore></ignore> -->
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>



</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are able to access the SQ pages from browser from your laptop. Then network connectivity to the instance seems fine. I would check on the authorization of the SQ to check if anyuser can initiate a scan. If restricted user can initiate the scan then I will have to pass the config in the POM.xml

See http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Authorization#Authorization-ProjectPermissions